# Using Gorilla FormatCloseMessage client receives wrong code

Tags: go, gorilla

I am closing a WS connection with the code 1008.

```
cm := websocket.FormatCloseMessage(websocket.ClosePolicyViolation, msg)
if err := c.conn.WriteMessage(websocket.CloseMessage, cm); err != nil {
    log.Error(err)
}
err = c.conn.Close()
```

However when receiving the message with [WS](https://github.com/websockets/ws) library, it says the code is 1006. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The code in the question writes the message to the network.  To debug, add a `time.Sleep(time.Second)` before the call to close. Perhaps that might give some insight into where the message is going.

Comment: I will try it out tomorrow. The thing is that the correct string message reaches the client.

Comment: The content of `cm` is written to the network as is. If the client receives the message in `cm`, then the incorrect code is probably a client issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the connection is instantly closed after sending the message the close handshake is not completed. One way to fix it is by adding a `sleep` call. Though it would be better to implement the close handshake correctly.